# Versions missing from shadow copies on Windows 2012

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012

Our Windows 2012 file server is configured to take shadow copies every hour. The drive is configured with 186GB of space.

I've personally been working on an Access database which I've modified many times over the past two weeks. I've just gone to restore an earlier version and there was only one version in shadow copies from 27th June. I expected there to be a lot more. Not a disaster as DPM also backs up the server overnight so it has the nightly copy. DPM has copies from 13th, 21st, 26th, 27th and 28th which sounds reasonable. I didn't modify it ever day.

This perplexed me. I then checked a PST which is updated frequently (yeah I know about PSTs in network drives!) and it has many more copies every hour except even they only go back to 27th June.

My first thought was that the 186GB space reserved for shadow copies was filling up but when I look at details it shows it using just 16GB.

So what am I missing? There is plenty of space in shadow copies so I would expect there to be many more copies of that PST (and my Access database). Why is shadow copy not using all 186GB?